# “movie theater binges and wing crawls”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I’ve found this sentence while reading a book.

> [S]he wouldn’t relate to his carefree days of movie theater binges and wing crawls with his dorm buddies.

In this context, what is the meaning of the phrase “wing crawls?” I’ve learned that the word ‘crawl’ can denote something like ‘drinking after drinking,’ but still have no idea what that ‘wing’ is. It may be that I’ve misunderstood the structure of the sentence at all. Could anybody help with this?

Comment: +1 if you edit the question and cite the title of the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Food crawl from the urban dictionary.

> Visiting multiple restaurants in an evening to obtain one complete and proper meal. This may be done as a dine-in or take-out experience. It is most often a practice where restaurants have one tasty item, and everything else on the menu ranged from only moderately good to shit.
>   Well if you can't decide where to eat, quit wasting my time and let's do a food crawl.

As for "movie theater binges"

> Binge — a period of excessive indulgence in an activity, especially
>   drinking alcohol or eating.

To summarize, the sentence could mean that the character with his friends watches one movie after another in one or multiple movie theater and while doing it orders and eats a lot of chicken wings from fast foods or movie theaters.

Comment: So "wings" just means "food"? Do you have any source for that?

Comment: @oerkelens no, a specific type of food - here's an example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_wing

Comment: It's worth adding that "wing crawl" combined with "dorm buddies" emphasizes the narrator's reference to their "carefree days", as buffalo wings are a stereotypical American college/fraternity junk food, often eaten in excess and sold at restaurants/bars targeted at the college crowd.

Answer (score 16):

A "wing crawl" appears to be similar to a "pub crawl", i.e. visiting several pubs on a single evening, having a drink or two in each.  However, the consumption of chicken wings is added.

From "[The Chicken's Wing - The one-stop-shop for all things chicken wings in London!](http://thechickenswing.net/wings%20on%20tour)"

> **Wing Crawls**
>
> It's exactly how it looks and it's as good as it sounds. We’ve all
>   been on a pub crawl, right? So just imagine this but add chicken wings
>   to the beer you’re just about there!

A sample advertising image

[image: A sample advertising image]

Comment: +1 for addressing the specific question of what a "wing" is.